# Can we say that $x^4$ is concave upwards for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

As we know the second derivative of this function is zero at $x = 0$, but $x = 0$ is not a point of inflection as a point of inflection is a point about which concavity changes but here concavity is same on left and right of $x = 0$ which is upwards, so $x = 0$ in not point of inflection, and as function is defined at $x = 0$ so can we say conclude by this that function is concave upwards for all x.

Comment: Function concave upwards iff the derivative is increasing. Therefore $x^4$ is concave upwards.

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, the function is concave upwards on all of  $\Bbb R$. The "no" is more technical:  I wouldn't say  it's concave upwards "for all $x\in\Bbb R$", because that doesn't quite make sense: A function is concave or not _on an interval_, not at a point. (Never mind that, pretend I just said yes...)

Comment: There is an alternate version of the definition of concave (see [convex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function)).  In this setting, the zero of the second derivative at $0$ is not relevant and you can see that the function is concave up.

Comment: yes, for all $x$ concave up, including $0$. Never mind derivatives, the definition of concavity does not involve any derivatives (as pointed above). Another example is $f(x)=|x|$ concave up for all $x$, even if $f'(0)$ does not exist, and $f''(x)=0$ for all $x\not=0$. (Also, as pointed above, concave up on the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$, though one could define concave up at $a$ too.)

Answer (score 1):

Given function :$f(x) = x^4 \implies f’(x) = 4x^3 $ It can be seen that derivative of the function is monotonically non-decreasing then on following [properties](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties) of concave up or convex function, it can be concluded that it is all concave up function.

Answer (score 1):

The second derivative test says that a twice-differentiable function $f$ is concave upward on an interval *if and only if* $f''(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ in that interval. The second derivative of $x^4$ is $12x^2$, which is clearly non-negative on $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore the function is concave upward on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

The graph of a function is concave up wherever $f''(x) > 0$, which is the case here for all $x \neq 0$. However, when we apply the formal definition of an increasing  function to $f'(x)$, it follows that $f'(x)$ is increasing over $R$; and so, $f(x) = x^{4}$ is concave up over $R$.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your definition of convexity, I think. The definition I prefer is to say that $f$ is concave up on $[a,b]$ when for every $x_1,x_2,x_3\in[a,b]$ with $a\le x_1<x_2<x_3\le b$, the slope from $\bigl(x_1,f(x(1)\bigr)$ to $\bigl(x_2,f(x_2)\bigr)$ is *less than* the slope from $\bigl(x_1,f(x(1)\bigr)$ to $\bigl(x_3,f(x_3)\bigr)$. Write out the inequality and simplify and get the condition
$$
x_1[f(x_2) - f(x_3)]\, +\, x_2[f(x_3) - f(x_1))]\, + \,x_3[f(x_1)-f(x_2)]\>>\>0\,.
$$
With this definition, $f(x)=x^{2n}$ is concave upwards.

Note that the above definition does not mention derivatives, so it’s perfectly good for non-differentiable functions, and does not say what convexity *at a point* might be.

Comment: $(+1)$: a nicely rigorous answer! :)